# How to update Swift from 3.0.1 to 3.0.2?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have two machines with same versions of Xcode (8.2.1) but different versions of Swift (3.0.1 and 3.0.2). How do I update Swift from 3.0.1 to 3.0.2?

Comment: simplified title and question

Comment: How do you know the Swift versions are different? Also, are they the same Xcode _build_?

Comment: Type in terminal  'xcrun swift -version'

Comment: So how i can update it/

Comment: Now i drag and drop 2nd storyboard controller to main storyboard then link with tab bar item. It is easy way.